# Cannot use _ as value

Tags: go

I saw a piece of code used to print values passed in arguments:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
  for _, val := range os.Args[1:] {
     fmt.Printf("%d %s \n", _ , val)
  }
}
```

Original program had a note that `_` holds index but was not printing it. When I tried to print index, I am getting below error:
`./main.go:8:16: cannot use _ as value`

What is the issue here?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

_(underscore) in Golang is known as the [Blank Identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) and it's value can't be used(it kind of doesn't hold any value).

Go doesn't allow you to have a unused variable therefore, original program used `_` to drop the value and compile the program successfully. Use `i` instead of `_` and run the program.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
  for i, val := range os.Args[1:] {
     fmt.Printf("%d %s \n", i , val)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note this is different from python where using `_` is just a naming convention